# amsfonts become pixelated in PDF

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx, pdf

I'm completely new to LaTeX. I've downloaded LyX 1.6.8 which uses MiKTeX 2.9, so there is probably some markup which is not required. When I create a PDF from this a bitmap font of AMSFonts is used.

If I uncomment `\usepackage{palatino}` (**EDIT** like it is below) the font is smooth, so I guess this has to be the problem. According to the documentation of AMSFonts the type 1 font is included. It just seems it's not used.

Thanks for your time!

```
%% LyX 1.6.8 created this file.  For more info, see [Link removed].
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true, 
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={My Title}}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.0.2
% see [Link removed] for more info

\usepackage{amsfonts}\usepackage{array}\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{palatino}
\title{My Title}
\author{Mene}
\date{2010-12-14T21:45:48.12}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\maketitle

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: (I just put the whole of your code into the code block)

Comment: I thought it was... anyway, thanks! (Maybe a problem with Opera?)

Comment: You don't use any AMS fonts in your sample. There aren't even any math environments. Please edit the code to include them, with the exact code causing you trouble. Anyway, when I tried your code, everything was Type 1, even if I added stuff from amsfonts.

Comment: i am amazed that the lyx/miktex combination you're using is giving you *any* bitmap fonts: sure, both computer modern and the amsfonts collection were originally implemented as bitmap fonts, but all modern distributions (including miktex 2.9) distribute outline versions of both. you _ought_ to be able to use amsfonts as type 1, without any adjustment, but the same is true of the computer modern "default" fonts. perhaps lyx is doing something crazy -- not being a lyx user, it's hard (for me) to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem was not amsfonts.
LyX simply used the default TeX font, which is a bitmap font. If you have the same problem, you can go to http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF for a solution.

What I did was to add `\usepackage{amsfonts}` from the very beginning and when I saw that adding `\usepackage{palatino}` solved the problem I wrongly deduced that amsfonts was not working as I want it to. I thought it would alter the default language as it includes type 1 versions of Computer Modern Typefaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{palatino}
```

This should be `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: Well that changes the font, but I'd like to use the AMSFont, just as a type 1 font