# Pixelated formula with amsmath

Tags: amsmath, math-fonts, pixelated

I just realized that my formulas become pixelated when I zoom-in on them and I don't know the reason. They look like this:

[image]

Here is a tiny MWE:

```
    \documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalpoint
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}  %Font type
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % For accents marks on spanish
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for rotating pages
\usepackage{lscape} % images as full page
\usepackage{enumerate} % for listing
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes} % for rotating tables and resizing
\usepackage{multirow} % multirows for tables

\usepackage{amsmath} % Equations
\usepackage{bm} % Equations

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\label{eqn:eqn4}
\boldsymbol{P(Kbar) =} 4.76Al - 3.01 - \left ( \frac{T(^{\circ}C) - 675}{85} \right ) \times [0.53Al + 0.005294 \times (T(^{\circ}C) - 675)]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

I've already installed `cm-super`from MPM and tried solutions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/amsfonts-become-pixelated-in-pdf) and others. Should I change the math font or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: there are thousands of thesis classes, which one are you using and what fonts does it use?

Comment: Sorry. I use MiKTeX and TexMaker, with garamondx font.

Comment: For this math formula, this is not garamondx. However, just in case: open the `MiKTeX console`.  In the `Tasks` menu, click on `Refresh font map files` (both as Administrator and as User).

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I misunderstood. I don't know the math font name but it's the LaTeX's default. Also, I did the 'Refresh font map files' on admin and user mode but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you post the thesis class, or copy and paste the lines from it that reproduce the bug? It’s likely selecting a font that you don’t have installed, and falling back to a bitmap METAFONT. Are you getting any warning messages?

Comment: By the way, you might have a look at `chemmacros` and `siunitx` for some of those formulas.

Comment: The concept of "classes" is not clear to me. This is my first document in LaTeX and basically I got an overleaf template and I've been modifying it ever since. I edited my question for showing all the packages that I've been adding.  Sounds crazy, but I've working with this for months and I almost finish it.